# Subalgebra of $L_\infty$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, von-neumann-algebras

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mathbb P)$ be a probability space. Let $\mathcal K$ be a unital $*$-subalgebra of $L_\infty(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mathbb P).$ Then by genearl theory of von neumann algebras we know that $\mathcal K$ is of the form $L_\infty(\Omega^\prime,\mathcal A^\prime,\mathbb P^\prime).$ Can we also take $(\Omega^\prime,\mathcal A^\prime,\mathbb P^\prime)\subseteq(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mathbb P)$?

Comment: Have you tried to consider the simpler situation for $C^*$-algebras first? If $A$ is a $C^*$-subalgebra of $C(X)$ with $X$ compact Hausdorff, is then $A \cong C(Y)$ for $Y$ a compact subspace of $X$?

Comment: I don't see why you'd conjecture this. Because $\Omega' \subset\Omega$ does not imply $L_\infty(\Omega')\subset L_\infty(\Omega)$.